# How do I get a Zotac MAG HD-ND01 to boot from a USB stick?

Tags: boot, bios

I have a Zotac MAG and there doesn't seem to be a way to get it to boot to a USB stick or drive via the boot menu.

How can I set this thing to boot from a USB stick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually hidden in the USB configuration tools, not the boot menu.

> Under Advanced > USB Configuration > USB config, try changing the USB Emulation from Auto to Hard disk. Exit, Save and enter BIOS again and see if you can choose the USB drive to boot up first.

Then hit F11 on boot to get the boot menu, choose "USB hard disk" and the Zotac should boot off of the USB stick.

- http://www.zotacusa.com/forum/topic/2218-zotac-mag-hd-nd01-does-not-boot-from-usb-hd-or-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer had me searched in bios option, the solution for me: 
->plug in your usb key prior to boot
->going in bios ([SUPPR])
->going in boot option, then select your usb key as first bootable device
->save & exit bios
Then it booted directly on my usb key

Answer (score -1):

To get to the Boot Menu in a Zotac computer, press the <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

Comment: Someone else mentioned F11 is the boot menu key. Has this changed recently?